# How to instantiate the IWebViewControl in MFC or C++?

Tags: c++, mfc, windows-runtime

Recently Microsoft has introduced `IWebViewControl` for WPF and winforms.
`IWebViewControl` uses the Edge rendering engine.
It is very easy to instantiate the `IWebViewControl` using the class constructor but I am not sure how to instantiate the `IWebViewControl` in MFC or C++.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/hosting/webview

Comment: You should propably tag your question [c++-winrt](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b-winrt/info) as this is the modern framework for using Windows Runtime in C++ applications.

Comment: @zett42: Not necessarily. C++/WinRT is *one* library, that can be used to activate Windows Runtime types. WRL is another. There are others, too. While I'd recommend using C++/WinRT myself, that also necessitates, that you have a C++17 compiler. Not everyone does, and MFC is a framework, that is often used in projects, that will only build with a specific version of Visual Studio. Adding the [tag:c++-winrt] tag may be inappropriate.

Comment: I have not tried it personally, however you can apparently host UWP controls in a native application.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/xaml-host-controls#uwp-xaml-hosting-api

Comment: How did you get on with this? Is it not possible for us to use the Win32 SDK in a MFC app?

Answer (score 0):

Here is IWebViewControl example in C++:
https://github.com/rjmurillo/webview-samples/tree/master/WinMD/Win32/WebViewSamples.Win32

Excerpt from the code:

```
void CheckFailure(_In_ HRESULT hr)
{
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        WCHAR message[512] = L"";
        StringCchPrintf(message, ARRAYSIZE(message), L"Error: 0x%x", hr);
        MessageBoxW(nullptr, message, nullptr, MB_OK);
        ExitProcess(-1);
    }
}

template <typename TInterface>
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<TInterface> GetActivationFactoryFailFast(_In_z_ PCWSTR factoryClassName)
{
    ComPtr<TInterface> factoryInstance;
    CheckFailure(RoGetActivationFactory(
        HStringReference(factoryClassName).Get(),
        IID_PPV_ARGS(&factoryInstance)));
    return factoryInstance;
}

template <typename TInterface>
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<TInterface> ActivateInstanceFailFast(_In_z_ PCWSTR className)
{
    ComPtr<TInterface> classInstanceAsInspectable;
    ComPtr<TInterface> classInstance;
    CheckFailure(RoActivateInstance(
        HStringReference(className).Get(),
        &classInstanceAsInspectable));
    CheckFailure(classInstanceAsInspectable.As(&classInstance));
    return classInstance;
}

ComPtr<IUriRuntimeClass> CreateWinRtUri(_In_z_ PCWSTR uri, _In_ bool allowInvalidUri = false)
{
    auto uriRuntimeClassFactory = GetActivationFactoryFailFast<IUriRuntimeClassFactory>(RuntimeClass_Windows_Foundation_Uri);
    ComPtr<IUriRuntimeClass> uriRuntimeClass;
    if (!allowInvalidUri)
    {
        CheckFailure(uriRuntimeClassFactory->CreateUri(HStringReference(uri).Get(), &uriRuntimeClass));
    }
    else
    {
        uriRuntimeClassFactory->CreateUri(HStringReference(uri).Get(), &uriRuntimeClass);
    }
    return uriRuntimeClass;
}

m_processOptions = ActivateInstanceFailFast<IWebViewControlProcessOptions>(RuntimeClass_Windows_Web_UI_Interop_WebViewControlProcessOptions);
ComPtr<IWebViewControlProcessFactory> webViewControlProcessFactory = GetActivationFactoryFailFast<IWebViewControlProcessFactory>(RuntimeClass_Windows_Web_UI_Interop_WebViewControlProcess);
CheckFailure(webViewControlProcessFactory->CreateWithOptions(m_processOptions.Get(), &m_process));
ComPtr<IAsyncOperation<WebViewControl*>> createWebViewAsyncOperation;
CheckFailure(m_process->CreateWebViewControlAsync(reinterpret_cast<INT64>(m_hostWindow), HwndWindowRectToBoundsRect(m_hostWindow), &createWebViewAsyncOperation));
HRESULT hr = createWebViewAsyncOperation->put_Completed(Callback<IAsyncOperationCompletedHandler<WebViewControl*>>([this, createWebViewAsyncOperation](IAsyncOperation<WebViewControl*>*, AsyncStatus status) -> HRESULT
{
    CheckFailure(createWebViewAsyncOperation->GetResults(&m_webViewControl));
    NavigateToUri(L"https://www.bing.com/");
    return S_OK;
}).Get());
CheckFailure(hr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is an answer as such and will remove it on request. MBut Microsoft now have a WebView2 in beta and it has a Win32 variant:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/win32

Since MFC is a Win32/Win64 app is it not possible to use this SDK?